# Is there a command for PCA for all variables in the dataset without selecting each variable one by one

Tags: dataset, stata, pca

I'm running a PCA in Stata on a dataset which has more than 20 variables and I want to execute the PCA for all the variables except for the ID column. I'm using the PCA command and selecting all variables one by one but ran into this error - "insufficient observations"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ds, not` to get a list of variables. This runs PCA on all the variables in the cars dataset *other than* make:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 automobile data)

. ds make, not
price         mpg           rep78         headroom      trunk         weight        length        turn          displacement  gear_ratio    foreign

. pca `r(varlist)'

Principal components/correlation                 Number of obs    =         69
                                                 Number of comp.  =         11
                                                 Trace            =         11
    Rotation: (unrotated = principal)            Rho              =     1.0000

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Component |   Eigenvalue   Difference         Proportion   Cumulative
    -------------+------------------------------------------------------------
           Comp1 |      6.79324      5.46883             0.6176       0.6176
           Comp2 |      1.32441       .30291             0.1204       0.7380
           Comp3 |       1.0215      .508122             0.0929       0.8308
           Comp4 |      .513382      .100772             0.0467       0.8775
           Comp5 |       .41261      .119505             0.0375       0.9150
           Comp6 |      .293105     .0368205             0.0266       0.9417
           Comp7 |      .256285      .101664             0.0233       0.9650
           Comp8 |      .154621     .0290009             0.0141       0.9790
           Comp9 |       .12562     .0474784             0.0114       0.9904
          Comp10 |     .0781414     .0510665             0.0071       0.9975
          Comp11 |     .0270749            .             0.0025       1.0000
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

Principal components (eigenvectors) 

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Variable |    Comp1     Comp2     Comp3     Comp4     Comp5     Comp6     Comp7     Comp8     Comp9    Comp10    Comp11 | Unexplained 
    -------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------
           price |   0.1835    0.5458   -0.4885    0.1144   -0.4743    0.2108    0.0601   -0.2901   -0.2067   -0.0933   -0.0897 |           0 
             mpg |  -0.3212   -0.0930    0.1234   -0.3734   -0.3655    0.5508    0.3699    0.3308    0.0971   -0.2012    0.0194 |           0 
           rep78 |  -0.1900    0.5922    0.1615   -0.6208    0.3485   -0.1553    0.1048   -0.1592   -0.0844    0.1126   -0.0014 |           0 
        headroom |   0.2190    0.1345    0.6954    0.1418   -0.4623   -0.3501    0.2767   -0.0996   -0.0675   -0.0546    0.0012 |           0 
           trunk |   0.2838    0.2425    0.4326    0.0782    0.0974    0.5786   -0.5421    0.0985   -0.0844    0.0923    0.0619 |           0 
          weight |   0.3696    0.0843   -0.1034   -0.0464    0.0912    0.0301    0.2026   -0.0230    0.3783   -0.0953    0.8003 |           0 
          length |   0.3614    0.0892    0.0338    0.0211    0.3077    0.0810    0.1814   -0.0264    0.4189   -0.5314   -0.5168 |           0 
            turn |   0.3444   -0.1055   -0.0302    0.0664    0.3367    0.1419    0.4825    0.2099   -0.6727    0.0429    0.0153 |           0 
    displacement |   0.3601    0.0631   -0.1267   -0.1455   -0.1471   -0.0450    0.1232    0.3666    0.3234    0.6915   -0.2705 |           0 
      gear_ratio |  -0.3254    0.1044    0.1370    0.4778    0.2248    0.3230    0.3951   -0.3736    0.2282    0.3642   -0.0283 |           0 
         foreign |  -0.2777    0.4740   -0.0416    0.4236    0.0912   -0.1915    0.0051    0.6650    0.0357   -0.1501    0.0774 |           0 
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Your error does suggest that something else is giving you trouble, but hard to diagnose what is going wrong without additional details (number of variables, observations, and patterns of missing data).

Comment: This is bang-on as a Stata reply. I want to add that a PCA of everything quantitative is usually a bad idea. The only exceptions are whenever everything is a series of measures of broadly the same phenomenon.

Comment: I could not agree more, @NickCox!